Ring a nearby Apple Airtag with an Android phone?
Linked with Why can't my Android phone play a sound on a nearby Apple AirTag? but not a duplicate.
Can an Android phone:

show that an AirTag (that I own) is nearby?
make it ring?

This article seems to show that the answer is yes, but the limitations make it totally unusable!

Apple Tracker Detect: user review (translated):

[...] it is indicated that it must not be near the owner's iPhone (via Bluetooth) and that the system can take up to 15 minutes to locate it. Finally, to make it ring, you have to wait 10 minutes while standing next to it, as it says!


AirGuard - AirTag protection: user reviews indicate it's really not handy to use


TL;DR: How to ring a nearby Apple Airtag (that I own) with an Android phone?
Is there a solution an Android that dosent't require to wait 10/15 minutes to locate a tag and doesn't require to be outside of a 15 meters range from the tag for it to work? (in this case another nearby Apple device is probably necessary)
